# Displaying images in an Emacs process running within iTerm2

Tags: image, emacs, terminal, iterm2, eshell

I want to display inline images in a Emacs process running in iTerm2. Here is a demonstration of what I'm expecting, using [`imgcat`](https://www.iterm2.com/utilities/imgcat) (a iTerm2 shell integration utility).

[image]

To begin with, I executed the following code within an `*eshell*` buffer. The rationale is that if this works out, I can simply setup a separate window dedicated to running `eshell`, and then update the image with a hook.

```
imgcat -u https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-icon.png
```

However, all I got is a bunch of base64 characters, even if I have set `TERM` to `xterm-256color` (was `dumb`).

[image]

The reason I chose `eshell` instead of `shell`, `term`, `ansi-term` or anything else is that it's implemented in Emacs Lisp, so it should be the most extensible one. On the other hand, using other terminal emulators is also OK if you find them more handy.

Comment: It sounds like imgcat needs to integrate with the shell.  You need to use a supported shell or add support for Eshell.  Or you can use a GUI Emacs (which can display inline images in buffers if it's compiled with that support enabled) and figure out how to add image support in shell, term, or eshell buffer.